# How to delete subclass pointer where use parent pointer as formal parameters in function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I meet a question when I delete subclass point. I want to delete subclass pointer use parent class pointer as formal parameters.  And there is my code likes follows.

```
class Test
{
public:
    virtual ~Test() = default;
    int a =10;
};
class TestChild : public Test
{
public:
    int c ;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(){
        TestChild* tc = new TestChild();
        tc->c = 19;
        delTest(tc);
    }
    void delTest(Test* &ds){
        delete ds;
        ds = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Bulid the project I will get an error:

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Test*&' to an rvalue of type 'Test*'
```

If I modify the function to `void delTest(Test**ds){ delete *ds; *ds=nullptr;}` and `delTest(&tc);`, I also got an error:

```
invalid conversion from 'TestChild**' to 'Test**'
```

What do I need to do to make my code work?

Comment: If function parameter is `Test * & ds` then you need to pass a reference to `Test *`.

Comment: In my code when function parameter is ```Test * &```, I think the ```tc``` is a reference to ```Test *```. But it not worked. Are there any other errors here? @user7860670

Comment: I do make my destructor to ```virtual```, but I not code in my question. I'm sorry about that. And thanks for your answer.@Ted Lyngmo

Comment: `tc` is `TestChild *` Attempt to bind a reference to `Test *` to an object of `TestChild *` type is the cause of an error here. Note that even though `TestChild` derives from `Test`, pointers to those types are unrelated types.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know the reason of this error. And I found a way to resolve it. I think I need to learn more about C++. Thank you again. @user7860670

Comment: It worked well with you solution. Also there are still some things I don't understand. But I will figure it out.  Thank you very much! @Ted Lyngmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to do to make my code work?

You could make function templates to support `delete` and `delete[]` + setting the pointer to `nullptr`:

```
template<typename T>
void delete_and_nullify_single_element_pointer(T*& ptr) {
    delete ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
void delete_and_nullify_array_pointer(T*& ptr) {
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}
```

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        TestChild* tc = new TestChild;
        tc->c = 19;
        delete_and_nullify_single_element_pointer(tc);
    }
};
```